# Can I mix the RESTs API and GraphQL in ASP.NET CORE Web API Application?

Tags: c#, rest, graphql, .net-5

I build an API (monolithic) with ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 5) and follow the restful API convention (so It is a restful API), and the data output is will use by the mobile app (flutter)

With a database that looks really complex (more than 20 tables...), I use the SQL Server and EF Core to work with this.

With CRUD basic, I code really easy, but when I one to query which are with lots of options like searching, sorting, and filtering...I feel stressed with the logic of the search, filter, sort function, and a lot of GET requests (they are same others, but different the output model)

I know that GraphQL can allow 1 endpoint but can get, query, sort, filter many things, really easy and lite. But I'm confused that I have already built the src code in restful style, so can I implement the GraphQL into my project. In my imagine, It will be like that: Create, Update, Delete with restful but Read with GraphQL.

Will .net 5 accept that??? and someone has met or do somethings like this please give me some advice.

Thanks for reading.